# SURF feature detection for linear panoramas OpenCV

Tags: opencv, video-processing, panoramas

I have started on a project to create linear/ strip panorama's of long scenes using video. This meaning that the panorama doesn't revolve around a center but move parallel to a scene eg. vid cam mounted on a vehicle looking perpendicular to the street facade.

The steps I will be following are:

1. capture frames from video
2. Feature detection - (SURF)
3. Feature tracking (Kanade-Lucas-Tomasi)
4. Homography estimation
5. Stitching Mosaic.

So far I have been able to save individual frames from video and complete SURF feature detection on only two images. I am not asking for someone to solve my entire project but I am stuck trying complete the SURF detection on the remaing frames captured.

**Question:** How do I apply SURF detection to successive frames? Do I save it as a YAML or xml?

For my feature detection I used OpenCV's sample find_obj.cpp and just changed the images used.

Has anyone experienced such a project? An example of what I would like to achieve is from Iwane technologies http://www.iwane.com/en/2dpcci.php

Answer (score 1):

While working on a similar project, I created an `std::vector` of SURF keypoints (both points and descriptors) then used them to compute the pairwise matchings.
The vector was filled while reading frame-by-frame a movie, but it works the same with a sequence of images.

There are not enough points to saturate your memory (and use yml/xml files) unless you have very limited resources or a very very long sequence.

Note that you do not need the feature tracking part, at least in most standard cases: SURF descriptors matching can also provide you an homography estimate (without the need for tracking).

**Reading to a vector**

Start by declaring a vector of Mat's, for example `std::vector<cv::Mat> my_sequence;`.
Then, you have two choices:

1. either you know the number of frames, then you resize the vector to the correct size. Then, for each frame, read the image to some variable and copy it to the correct place in the sequence, using `my_sequence.at(i) = frame.clone();` or `frame.copyTo(my_sequence.at(i));`
2. or you don't know the size beforehand, and you simply call the `push_back()` method as usual: `my_sequence.push_back(frame);`

Comment: Thanks for your help Sansuio! What is your similar project?

Comment: A few years ago I wrote a small command line app to detect SURFs in each frame of a movie, then computed stabilization results and rolling shutter corrections from the pairwise homographies. I also gave this linear panorama from SURF task as an assignemnt to students in my university during my PhD ;-)

Comment: Do you still have that assignment and some possible notes to help me through it? well notes to help someone with out a computer science degree? :)

Comment: Sorry, no notes. But your project is tractable without too much knowledge, so we hsoul dbe able to help you when you have specific  questions.

Comment: Sansuiso, I have been looking on how to put my images into std::vector but found myself a bit lost. Can you elaborate on this further or link me to a tutorial on how to use a sequence of images in a vector?